# Problems with Python plotting and logscaling

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm trying to do a simple plotting with log-scaling in Python. But I don't know what I'm doing wrong, since it won't work. I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows 8, Matplotlib 1.3.1. Can anybody help?

Here's the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 5)*1000000)

plt.yscale('log')
plt.plot(df)
```

or:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.semilogy(df)
```

or:

```
df.plot(logy=True)
```

But no matter how I do I always end with the following error message:

```
In [7]: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 495, in callit
func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 363, in        idle_draw
self.draw()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 348, in draw
FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 451, in draw
self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1034, in draw
func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 2086, in draw
a.draw(renderer)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1093, in draw
renderer)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1042, in _get_tick_bboxes
extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 754, in get_window_extent
bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 329, in _get_layout
ismath=ismath)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 210, in get_text_width_height_descent
self.mathtext_parser.parse(s, self.dpi, prop)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 3009, in parse
self.__class__._parser = Parser()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 2193, in __init__
- ((lbrace + float_literal + rbrace)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: What' is the matplotlib version. I run the code in 1.3.0 without exception. By the way, there are negative values in the random data, which can't be ploted on log axis.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that! It's 1.3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found some discussion about mixed installation, where you've added and upgraded your installation at different times and begun to suspect that there might be some mixed versions problem. I then uninstalled matplotlib and tried to reinstall it and stumbled upon the next problem: 'error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat' and there's some discussion about that in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat). So then I had to install MinGW and finally ended up with reinstalling (and also upgrading some packages like Numpy and Pandas) the whole Python stack from the beginning. After this process the plotting problems were gone.

Of course this isn't the true answer to the problem but at least it solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be a known bug. See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2338

Comment: Thanks but that probably wasn't the reason. See following.